# MS Access SQL - Average of 3 Previous Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column of values where I need to take the average of the two previous values and the current value and display as a new column.  I'm using MS Access 2013 and am more familier using SQL code rather than the SQL Query Wizard. So, if you could provide the code I'd appreciate it.

I've read on other threads that talked about a Lag function, but I believe Access does not allow that.  Also, I've seen similar questions answered with subqueries, but I'm not familiar enough with those yet.

Below is what I'm looking for. Given column A (1,2,3,4,5) how do I make B (0,0,2,3,4)?

```
A   |  B
----------
1   |  0  
2   |  0 
3   |  2   =  (1+2+3)/3
4   |  3   =  (2+3+4)/3
5   |  4   =  (3+4+5)/3
```

Comment: *So, if you could provide the code I'd appreciate it.*...you might be mistaking StackOverflow for a different site. We are volunteer programmers not here to do free work but to help fellow programmers resolve issues with earnest attempts. Please learn from tutorials and give it a try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question provides no previous attempt at solving the problem and expects SO users to do all of the work for them

Comment: My apologies. I deleted my code due to it not doing anything I needed.  I was looking for assistance here.  I apologize if it looked like I'm just looking for someone to do the work.  I'll remove the question if need be.  I appreciate the help Matt!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a self join to the same table for when the value of A is BETWEEN a - 2 and A.

```
SELECT
    t.A
    ,SUM(pre.A) / 3 as B
FROM
    TableName t
    LEFT JOIN TableName pre
    ON pre.A >= (t.A - 2)
    AND pre.A <= t.A
GROUP BY
    t.A
```

Note that this will actually give you 0,1,2,3,4.  If you want 0,0,2,3,4 you will have to count the preceding rows to determine if there are three and if not make it 0 such as:

```
SELECT
    t.A
    ,IIF(COUNT(pre.A) < 3, 0, SUM(pre.A) / 3) as B
FROM
    TableName t
    LEFT JOIN TableName pre
    ON pre.A >= (t.A - 2)
    AND pre.A <= t.A
GROUP BY
    t.A
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying, "Between operator without And in query expression 'pre.A BETWEEN t.A -'  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3827129 just switch it to >= and <=, I have updated but not tested.  BETWEEN is inclusive of the high and low so combining like this should give you desired result

Comment: It looks like that should work, but all Access tells me is, "Running Query".  I assume it's b/c I have a very large dataset? Like, 52,000 records.